# Sending booleans over the internet (Windows & Linux)

Tags: c++, windows, linux, boolean

I'm sending information from my server to clients and back again using packed structs (obviously there are a lot more data in the structs)

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)

struct other_data_struct
{
int hp;
int wp;
char movetype;
}

struct PlayerStats
{
int playerID;
other_data_struct data;
bool friendly;    //<-this one messes up how the others are going to be packed on the 2 systems
}
#pragma pack(pop)
```

That works fine for all fixed sized variables, ints and chars and even other structs.

The boolean doesn't work well though when the server is compiled with gcc for Linux and the client is compiled with MSVC for windows...

I have thought of making some sort of container (ie. a unsigned char with 8 boolean get/set functions or similar) but it seems as quirky as inelegant.

Is there some way to 'pack' structs containing boolean variables exactly the same on Windows and Linux or should I bite the sour apple and use a char for each boolean?

Comment: This isn't a very safe way of doing serialization if you ever interact with a system with different endian-ness even if you're able to solve this problem.

Comment: Well I guess you are right but I will definitely notice if gcc or MSVC starts to pack things differently and act in consequence. I don't plan to use any other system.

Comment: Is the problem with the boolean which bit of the byte it populates? In that case you could use an `unsigned char` instead.

Comment: I'm using a char ATM and it works OK, any boolean get's stuck away in different places with gcc / MSVC.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Is `sizeof(bool)` different on the two systems?

Comment: Please don't say 'ATM'! I'm a native English speaker and it still took me a while to work it out. This is an international forum!

Comment: Ok, I'll drop that (ATM). Otherwise the problem is that the packed structs differs, you cant just cast it on a predefined struct.

Comment: You're not making this easy for us, Valmond! Put some members into that struct of yours, and then tell us how they differ.

Comment: For easiest portability, avoid types that aren't size-explicit.  Use int32_t, not int.  int16_t, not short.  intX_t, not bool.  `struct { int8_t a; int8_t b; int8_t c; int8_t d; };` will pack the same on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [bitfields](http://tdistler.com/2008/07/21/cc-using-bitfields-effectively), that way your packed struct contains 'int', but your code uses a more space-efficient representation.

I believe bitfields have some awful performance characteristics, so they may not be the way to go if you care more about access time than space usage.

Comment: you mean like int:3 and such? IIRC I have tried and that wasn't 'encoded' the same way on the both platforms. Good idea though.

Comment: Given that bitfields are generally used for interfacing with hardware (see the examples in the linked blog), I'm surprised that you would have different representations on the two sides.  Perhaps you have problems if you don't fully specify all 32-bits?  (If a struct just contains 'int flags:3' is it legal for the struct to be 8-bits wide?)

Comment: One danger in bit fields is that you have no guarantee how they will be packed within a word.  GCC does it differently depending on the target.  So 8 1-bit fields could be packed in opposite order using the same compiler on two different CPU types.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Google Protocol Buffers instead of your own packed structures. Or you could eschew bool to avoid the incompatibility.

If I really had to start from where you are and make it work, I'd make a little program with the structs in it and start experimenting with additional padding fields until I came up with something that looked precisely the same on the two systems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but converting my ~100 structs to 'fast small xml' seems not what I'm looking for and the second idea is what I'm trying to evince ;-)

Comment: Have you actually read about pbufs? There's no XML involved at all. You turn your struct into an abstract definition, and then a code gen generates fast code that packs and unpacks in a binary format.

Comment: Now I have and well... I'm not going to use them as I won't change my whole setup (which would involve, ... really much testing and a lot of coding) but if it works as how I understood it, it means platform independent and , particularly, a 'class' that will compile with your code (c++/java/whatever), if that's it, then this is probably the future way of how to communicate (Except of course if Boost invents something).

Comment: I'm still in the past though so I have to go on with was done several years ago. I'd give you a +2 if I could though, some years from now I will reap the knowledge of your intervention, might it be pbufs or its successor.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you transfer data between different systems, you should not rely on how these systems represent the data in memory, because the memory representation may vary with the processor architecture, the compiler options, and many other things. You should use some library for serialization instead, since the authors of that library have already put many thoughts into all kinds of problems that you are probably not interested in.

Comment: That might give the answer as an integer or a char is known for their sizes etc. on different systems (which means no you can't).

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, you should not make assumptions about endianess, size of fields, structure packing etc.  For general application or library development, it would be bad practice to do this kind of thing.

That said, I do this kind of thing fairly often when working on embedded systems where 1) memory (both RAM & executable ROM) is a precious resource, so unnecessary libraries need to be avoided and 2) I know my code will only target one platform, and 3) don't want to take the performance hit of packing/unpacking.  Even then, it's probably not a 'best' practice.

If you are aware of the risks of doing things this way, I think you answered this one yourself.  Define your own type for the boolean if you want to be 100% sure.  Also beware that the size of `long` differs between a 32-bit and 64-bit platform.  I usually stick with "stdint.h" types for every numeric primitive, that way you know what size you're dealing with.

Comment: Yes my concern isn't ram but bandwidth (and of course compatibility). Guess I'll have to stick with the old char then :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just serialize while calling ntohl, htonl, ntohs, htons, etc.  This will convert the endian-ness fine - and it's a little safer than what you're doing.  You have to worry more about compiler dependent things if you're using structs than if you're using core types of known sizes.

The functions put data in network byte order which is the standard for network transport between communicating devices.  Other network programmers will understand your code better too for maintenance purposes :)

Comment: Byte order is not his problem.

Comment: That would augment my workload really much, I have like about 100 structs, some have tens and tens of different variables and even arrays of other structs (like item[SHOWMAXNOFITEMS] where item has ~20variables). I always +1 (good) answers (so +1) but I can't imagine this one as an answer, sorry :-)

Comment: If he packed things individually (which this would require), he'd be translating his types manually which would take away any implementation dependence.  His problem is he's relying on the implementations matching up - it's just lucky he got that far without a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that :) hope you find a quicker solution man.

Comment: I actually didn't get that far without a problem, that's why I'm here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on what the problem would be.  Both Windows and Linux define `bool` as a one-byte object.

Windows **does** define `BOOL` as an `int`, so if you're putting a `BOOL` on the wire and reading it as a `bool` (or putting a `bool` on the wire and reading it as a `BOOL`) then you're going to have trouble.  That's relatively easy to fix.

It may be that Windows and Linux define different values for `false` and `true` (more likely, they agree that `false` is `0`, but don't agree on the value used for `true`; even outside of network programming it's possible to have `bool` variables that are aren't `true` or`false`, see below).  The Standard requires that `bool`s be at least one byte, and a byte has far more than two possible values.

Yes, converting your `bool`s to `unsigned char`s and sending **that** over the wire will work fine.

---

**Note**:  "`bool` variables that are aren't `true` or `false`":

```
// obviously this code won't show up in anybody's code base
char a = 'a';
bool b = *reinterpret_cast<bool*>(&a);
switch (b) {
    case true:
       std::printf("true\n");
       break;
    case false:
       std::printf("false\n");
       break;
    default:
       std::printf("huh?\n");
       break;
 }
```

Comment: the problem is with 'packed' structs not how different compilers / OS handle values of itself.

Comment: The original question stated "The boolean doesn't work well though when the server is compiled with gcc for Linux and the client is compiled with MSVC for windows."  The clarification states "the problem is with 'packed' structs."  Perhaps a little more detail would help us stop shooting int the dark.